# Create a set from a list of sets

Tags: terraform, hcl

I am trying to create a predefined set of IAM roles.

```
locals {
    default_iam_roles = {
        group1 = {
            name = "group:group1-group@mydomain.com"
            roles = toset([
                "roles/viewer"
            ])
        }
        group2 = {
            name = "group:group2-group@mydomain.com"
            roles = toset([
                "roles/owner"
            ])
        }
    }

    formatted_iam_roles = [ for member in local.default_iam_roles : setproduct([member.name], member.roles) ]
}
```

If I print `local.formatted_iam_roles` I get the following:

```
[
  toset([
    [
      "group:group1-group@mydomain.com",
      "roles/viewer",
    ],
  ]),
  toset([
    [
      "group:group2-group@mydomain.com",
      "roles/owner",
    ],
  ]),
]
```

Now I want to create a single set which contains all of the combinations contained in the list, so that I can feed it to a resource on a `for_each` statement, but I am not able to find the logic for this.

The expected output would be:

```
toset([
  [
    "group:group1-group@mydomain.com",
    "roles/viewer",
  ],
  [
    "group:group2-group@mydomain.com",
    "roles/owner",
  ]
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation of taking multiple sets and deriving a new set which contains all of the elements across all of the input sets is called *[union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory))* and so Terraform's function for it is called [`setunion`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setunion) to follow that.

```
locals {
  all_iam_roles = setunion(local.formatted_iam_roles...)
}
```

The `...` symbol after the argument tells Terraform that it should use each element of `local.formatted_iam_roles` as a separate argument to `setunion`, because that function is defined as taking an arbitrary number of arguments that are all sets, rather than as taking a list of sets.

It might be helpful to think of `setunion` as being a similar sort of function as [`concat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/concat). The `concat` function joins multiple *lists* together, preserving each list's element order and the order the lists are given. Set elements don't have any particular order and contain each distinct value only once, and so the behavior of `setunion` is different but its purpose is related.

Comment: That was exactly what I was asking for and quite simpler than my map + merge approach. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

Your solution in the question was close, you just have to apply a [`flatten`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten) function to the `setproduct` output.

```hcl
locals {
  # ...
  formatted_iam_roles = [for member in local.default_iam_roles : flatten(setproduct([member.name], member.roles))]
}
```

The output will be the following:

```
formatted_iam_roles = [
  [
    "group:group1-group@mydomain.com",
    "roles/viewer",
  ],
  [
    "group:group2-group@mydomain.com",
    "roles/owner",
  ],
]
```

Now, if you really want it to make a set for the final result, you can use `toset`, most like it will be pointless:

```hcl
formatted_iam_roles = toset([for member in local.default_iam_roles : flatten(setproduct([member.name], member.roles))])
```

Comment: I tried that approach but in case someone defines more than one role for the same group it is not correct, as it will flatten each group combinations on a single list

Comment: I understand, probably this would have been something you would wanted to specify in the question.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have added a group with multiple roles so that it was considered, sorry for that

Comment: Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally faced the problem using maps instead of lists, because I needed to use a `for_each` argument and it doesn't accept a set of tuples as value.

If anyone knows a better approach, post it and I will be pleased of marking it as correct.

```
locals {
  formatted_iam_roles = merge([ for member in local.default_iam_roles :
                                    { for pair in setproduct([member.name], member.roles) :
                                          "${pair[0]}${pair[1]}" => { "name": pair[0], "role": pair[1] }
                                    }
                              ]...)
}
resource "google_project_iam_member" "team_access" {
  for_each = local.formatted_iam_roles

  project = var.project_id
  member  = each.value["name"]
  role    = each.value["role"]
}
```